# iOS - view inside stackview not showing up shadow

Tags: ios, shadow, uistackview

I have designed popup view using UIStackView. 
I'm trying to shadow to "Alert View" as showing in the picture. Parameters for shadow are shown at the right side.

[image: Storyboard design]

But it is not showing shadow after I run code.

[image: After running on device]

But if I design this popup without UIStackView, it shows up the shadow.

What is reason behind this?

Comment: check the answer posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your AlertView has `clipToBounds` ticked. Thats the reason why you dont see shadow added to `AlertView`. Uncheck it to work properly

**O/P with `clipToBounds` ticked**

[image]

[image]

**O/P after unchecking ClipToBounds **

[image]
[image]

**EDIT:**

Though am not sure, the `IBInspectable` you set up for properties like Shadow Radius might not be set up correctly, please try setting shadow programmatically

```
    self.alertView.layer.shadowRadius = 3
    self.alertView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2, height: 4)
    self.alertView.layer.shadowOpacity = 2
    self.alertView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
```

If this works then you can solve the issue with IBInspectables of yours

Comment: But unchecking "clipToBounds" is also not working in my case.

Comment: @pramod-more : did you uncheck it on aletView ? Not on stackView!

Comment: Yes, unchecked on both.

Comment: @pramod-more : Finally I believe shadow radius is your IBInspectable you added I dont know how is it set up can u try adding shadow programmatically ?

Comment: @pramod-more : or else paste the IBInspectable code you have for various properties like shadow Radius, offset etc

Comment: @pramod-more : am glad it did :) That means your IBInspectable set up must be having a issue :) Check that and then u can remove the code :) Happy coding